# Python indentation assistance

Tags: python

I am taking a Python programming class and am having an issue with my coding question.

The error I am getting says

```
SyntaxError: expected an indented block (CTest.py, line 5) 
 5  muffin -= 1:
```

I tried to indent muffin -= 1: again but it still gave me the same error. So I don't know what the problem is. I also tried to indent all the code below muffin -= 1:

Here is the question I am working on:

> You work for a bakery that sells two items: muffins and cupcakes. The
> number of muffins and cupcakes in your shop at any given time is
> stored in the variables muffins and cupcakes, which have been defined
> for you. Write a program that takes strings from standard input
> indicating what your customers are buying ("muffin" for a muffin,
> "cupcake" for a cupcake). If they buy a muffin, decrease muffins by
> one, and if they buy a cupcake, decrease cupcakes by 1. If there is no
> more of that baked good left, print ("Out of stock"). Once you are
> done selling, input "0", and have the program print out the number of
> muffins and cupcakes remaining, in the form "muffins: 9 cupcakes: 3"
> (if there were 9 muffins and 3 cupcakes left, for example).

```
buying = input()
while buying != "0":
    if buying == "muffin":
        while buying > 0:
        muffin -= 1:
    else print ("Out of stock"):
    elif buying == cupcake:
        if cupcake > 0:
        cupcake -= 1:
    else print ("Out of stock"):
        buying = input() 
        print("muffins:", muffins, "cupcakes:", cupcakes)
```

Comment: @khelwood Yes, but it does require a semi-colon. I'll reword my comment a little bit.

Comment: Unlike other languages like Java and C, Python does not require anything at the end of declarative lines like `muffin -= 1`.

Answer (score 2):

`while buying > 0:` should be `if muffin > 0:`. You need to indent the statement(s) that should be executed in that case, and the corresponding `else:` needs to be indented at the same level as `if`.

`else:` should be on a line of its own, with the statement(s) to execute after it, indented.

You shouldn't have `:` at the end of ordinary statements, only statements that start a block (`if`, `else`, and `while`).

And you need to quote `cupcake` when comparing with `buying`.

```
buying = input()

while buying != "0":
    if buying == "muffin":
        if muffin > 0:
            muffin -= 1
        else:
            print ("Out of stock")
    elif buying == "cupcake":
        if cupcake > 0:
            cupcake -= 1
        else:
            print ("Out of stock")
    buying = input() 

print("muffins:", muffins, "cupcakes:", cupcakes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. For example:

```
while buying > 0:
muffin -= 1:
```

should be

```
while buying > 0:
    muffin -= 1 # No ':' at the end, add one level of indentation to enter block
```

Answer (score 0):

There are manythings wrong here. First, you need to indent the blocks after `while` and `if`. e.g.:

```
    while buying > 0:
        muffin -= 1
```

I'm not sure how many lines you want to be inside the while block, but as written the while loop will never exit because the `buying` variable doesn't change.

Next, you have colons in weird places. E.g.:

```
muffin -= 1:
```

Should be:

```
muffin -= 1
```

Also, your `else` syntax is wrong in both locations:

```
else print ("Out of stock"):
```

I'm assuming you want something like:

```
else:
    print ("Out of stock")
```

And finally, the `cupcake` variable is never defined.

I didn't really look at the logic of whether it will do what you want. There's too much to  fix to understand what you were attempting.